# How to add function dynamically to a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a simple js code, but it doesn't work (no alert when checking the checkbox) what is the prob? :

```
function dynamicCheckbox() {          
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "chkbox";
        checkbox.id = "chkid" ;
        checkbox.style = "width:50px";
        checkbox.onclick = "openFiles()";            
}

function openFiles() {
    alert("hey");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign the function itself, not a string:

```
checkbox.onclick = openFiles;
```

Full example:

```js
function dynamicCheckbox() {          
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "chkbox";
        checkbox.id = "chkid" ;
        checkbox.style = "width:50px";
        checkbox.onclick = openFiles;
        
        document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
}

function openFiles() {
    alert("hey");
}

dynamicCheckbox();
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add event handle to dynamic control as

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
       if(e.target && e.target.id== 'chkid'){
            openFiles();
       }
});
```

```js
function dynamicCheckbox() {          
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "chkbox";
        checkbox.id = "chkid" ;
        checkbox.style = "width:50px";
        //checkbox.onclick = "openFiles()";
        document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
          if(e.target && e.target.id== 'chkid'){
            openFiles();
         }
        });
        
        document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
 
}

function openFiles() {
    alert("hey");
}

dynamicCheckbox();
```